# Nodejs user profiles and sessions

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

The goal is to build a user profile system for my web application. A user would be able to login, maintain a session and see his profile. After reading various tutorials online about how to do this, I feel a bit lost. Everyone uses different libraries and as someone new to web development, it's not clear what each library does. I've seen the following libraries used, can someone explain the flow of user-profile interactions and where each library comes in?

```
passport
passport-local
bcrypt-nodejs
connect-flash
express-session

jsonwebtoken
express-jwt

morgan
cookie-parser
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to start your learning can be at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1ktxiqyiLA
There I learned how to use the most of plugins from your question.

Ok so about the plugins:

- `passport` passport is a node.js plugin which is used usually with `express` that works as a middleware responsible for the `authorization` and `authentication`
- `passport-local` - is a plugin for `passport`, more technically a strategy of authentication which usually is used with a database or configuration file.
- `bcrypt-nodejs` is used usually for crypting the passwords in the database (but it is much more powerfull than that), is not cool to save password in plain text.
- `connect-flash` - is used for flash messages that appears on a page "The user was successfully added", "Invalid user credentials", or any other success or error messages that you want to display on a page.
- `express-session` - is an `express` middleware which is responsible to store the user session.
- `jsonwebtoken` - jwt is used to create a token which you will use to identify if an user was authenticated or not.
- `express-jwt` - an `express` middleware for `jsonwebtoken`
- `cookie-parser` - an `express` middleware to parse cookies
- `morgan` - just a log-ing service.

Ok so you should understand a bit of theory here:

- `passport` with `passport-local` strategy is a statefull authentication mechanism which is supposed to save if the user is authenicated or not in a session, if you restart the node.js server if you did not persist your sessions in a third party service as a database/file etc... you will lose the sessions.
- `jsonwebtoken` is a stateless authentication mechanism, you do not need to save anything on your server only the "secret key". Stateless architecture has some cool pros as it promotes horizontal scalability you can have endless nodes which will know how to parse the sended token and understand if the user is logged in or not. Lately I go with jwt as authentication.

Comment: Fantastic answer, it helps a lot! Can I clarify a couple of things? In the video you linked, they do not use the morgan module, is morgan not necessary? The video also does not use jsonwebtoken but uses express-session. Do I need to choose between jsonwebtoken and express-session? You said passport is a statefull authentication and jsonwebtoken is stateless authentication mechanism, but I've seen tutorials where both modules are used?

Comment: Yo can use them but usually they go alone, I do use json web token for api-s, and for monolit apps I go with passport. Morgan is used to save and display logs it is a debug tool.

Comment: The video tutorial uses handlebars. As far as I understand, if I want to use AngularJS or ReactJS then I probably won't use handlebars. Should I still use the solution in the video with passport and express-sessions?

Comment: For react or angular I suggest you to learn from the following tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens